# Should I use event aggregator only to prevent memory leaks?

Tags: c#, events, memory-leaks, prism, eventaggregator

We consider to use the [Prism event aggregator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Prism_Aggregator_Service.aspx) for the purpose of reducing memory leaks due to event references.

1. Is this for itself a valid reason to use this pattern? The other benefits are not interesting for us now. We plan to use it between model components and not UI.
2. Our problem was that some developers forgot to unregister events. I saw that Prism has one flavour which uses weak references but it has [limitations](http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.com/2009/05/prism-event-aggregator-subscription.html). The other flavour forces to explicitly Unsubscribe(), which again can be forgotten. So how is it better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Our problem was that some developers forgot to unregister events

If this is your problem, switching to the Prism event aggregator (or, using any other implementation) won't improve things.

Adding a new dependency with a new, non-trivial, usage pattern into a messy situation isn't going to tidy it up at all.

What you *need* is to clean up your code.

Instead of new code libraries, I'd suggest looking into static analysis tools like [fxCop](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6544) (aka Code Analysis), [Gendarme](http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme) and [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/). All of these are able to detect some situations where events are not unhooked or where IDisposable is not implemented properly.

Using static analysis, you can dispassionately identify code that needs cleanup. Throw in use of a memory profiler (like [dotTrace Memory](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)) and you'll be able to find the worst offenders and clean them up promptly.

#### Update

In answer to the question in the comment below:

> What do you suggest as a good pattern for ensuring that events get unhooked?

In can be difficult to make sure that all events are unsubscribed - but given the way that events are implemented (see [CLR via C#](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780735627048) for details), you can cheat a little by ensuring all event subscriptions are discarded.

Instead of

```
public event EventHandler<Fu> FuBar;
```

handle the event subscription yourself, like this:

```
public event EventHandler<Fu> FuBar {
    add { mFuBar += value; }
    remove { mFuBar -= value; }
}

private EventHandler<Fu> mFuBar;
```

Then, implement `IDisposable` on your class, and in your `Dispose()` method set `mFuBar` to `null`, discarding the subscriptions. FxCop (and other tools) can then tell you if you are failing to Dispose of the class.

Comment: +1, can't agree more. EventAggregator is meant as a message broker across the application and shoehorning it into a place where you'd normally use regular .NET Events is sometimes nontrivial (cross-talk between UIs, having to create distinct event classes for every usage to mitigate this, etc... not ideal). This is not what EventAggregator was meant to solve.

Comment: What do you suggest as a good pattern for ensuring that events get unhooked?  It would be nice, at least for events that are hooked when an object is created and will remain unchanged during the object's useful lifetime, to have a means of having the same block of code handle subscription and unsubscription (thus ensuring that the same events will get unsubscribed as were subscribed).  Unfortunately, I know of no even-remotely-clean way in vb or C# of doing such a thing.  Do you have a good pattern?

Comment: Implementing IDisposable in the Event source does not really add any value.  The memory leak happens when the subscriber has a shorter life span compared to the event source.  So, disposing the event source does really prevent the leak which has already happened when the subscribers are living in the memory only because they are referrenced by the event source.  Using Weak Event Pattern is the solution in such scenarios.

Comment: Using `IDisposable` in this way helps to mitigate the effects of the memory leak; If you're working in the context of processing a request for a webapp - where everything is about to be discarded anyway, then it adds nothing. But if you're working in a WinForms/WFP/UWP application where things tend to be longer lived, mitigations like this can prevent bugs from taking down the application.

Comment: Good point about static analyzers but @PramodBR is right here. The IDisposaility is adding nothing here.